# RestKit nested one-to-many relationship mapping is very slow

Tags: ios, restkit

In a few projects I'm working on, I've noticed that when one-to-many relationships are nested in an API response, relationship mapping is taking a very long time and causing a bottleneck on some loading screens.  I profiled the issue in instruments and there wasn't a single method that stood out, just several methods related to relationship mapping.  This issue persists even when core data is not being used.  I'm wondering if there are any settings, methods, or properties I could make use of to speed up the relationship mapping process.

I created a test project to highlight the issues.  The project has a test suite that uses RestKit and OHHTTPStubs to map some json fixtures into an array of custom objects.  The test project repo can be found here: https://github.com/rtimpone/restkit_relationship_mapping_benchmarking.  The data model used is simple, but makes use of a one-to-many relationship.  It does not use core data.  I benchmark the results of RestKit relationship mapping against manual mapping just as a reference point, I do not expect relationship mapping to be as quick as manual mapping.

Is there anything I can do when setting up RestKit or object mappings that would make relationship mapping quicker?  Is there some step I'm missing in setting up my mappings or response descriptors?  Is this performance typical when mapping nested relationships?  Any help or suggestions on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your test ran 20% faster just by introducing a cache in valueTransformersForTransformingFromClass and having RKDictionaryByMergingDictionaryWithDictionary to call addEntriesFromDictionary instead of using own logic that seems to do the same thing.
Be sure to clear the cache NSDictionary in addValueTransformer, removeValueTransformer and insertValueTransformer.

```
NSDictionary *RKDictionaryByMergingDictionaryWithDictionary(NSDictionary *dict1,      NSDictionary *dict2)
{
    if (! dict1) return dict2;
    if (! dict2) return dict1;

    NSMutableDictionary * const result = [dict1 mutableCopy];
    [result addEntriesFromDictionary:dict2];
    return result;
}

- (NSArray *)valueTransformersForTransformingFromClass:(Class)sourceClass toClass:(Class)destinationClass
{
    if (sourceClass == Nil && destinationClass == Nil) return [self.valueTransformers copy];
    else if (sourceClass == Nil || destinationClass == Nil) [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"If you specify a source or destination class then you must specify both."];
    @synchronized(self.valueTransformersForClassesCache)
    {
        NSString * const cacheKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_to_%@", NSStringFromClass(sourceClass), NSStringFromClass(destinationClass)];
        NSMutableArray *matchingTransformers = [self.valueTransformersForClassesCache valueForKey:cacheKey];
        if(!matchingTransformers)
        {
            matchingTransformers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.valueTransformers count]];
            for (RKValueTransformer *valueTransformer in self) {
                if (! [valueTransformer respondsToSelector:@selector(validateTransformationFromClass:toClass:)]
                || [valueTransformer validateTransformationFromClass:sourceClass toClass:destinationClass]) {
                    [matchingTransformers addObject:valueTransformer];
                }
        }

        [self.valueTransformersForClassesCache setObject:matchingTransformers forKey:cacheKey];
    }

    return [matchingTransformers copy];
}
```

Comment: the original RKDictionaryByMergingDictionaryWithDictionary does not simply merge two dictionaries; it merges all subdictionaries as well. your implementation is faster, but the result can be different.